# sdl_fillrect also fills my background

Tags: c++, sdl

my game has a background and a enemy that move.every time my enemy move i want to fill the last move but when i use `SDL_FillRect` it remove enemy with the background.but i want to have the background.

```
   int main( int argc, char* args[] )
    {
        towers mytowers;
        enemy myenemy;
        bool quit = false;
        bool backgroundflag=false;
        init();
        load_files();

        Mix_PlayMusic( music, -1 );


        while(castelhealth!=0)
        {
            mytowers.showtower();
            myenemy.path();
            SDL_FillRect( screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        }

        clean_up();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And the clip-rectangle of the surface isn't the complete surface?

Comment: i don't know.i haven't initialize clip-rectangle.

Comment: As the name suggests, `FillRect` fills specified rectangle with specified solid colour. As surface is not layered, there is no way for this function to know what is background and what isn't. You have to implement it yourself.